# jquery disabled next element if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

How do I disabled textbox if checkbox is checked.
I've got a few textboxes and checkboxes next to each other.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="checkbox" name="deposit_checked"> <input type="text" name="deposit_value">
<input type="checkbox" name="booking_checked"> <input type="text" name="booking_value">
<input type="checkbox" name="referral_checked"> <input type="text" name="referral_value">
</form>
```

I can do it individually with code below:

```
$("input[name=deposit_checked]").change(function(){

if( $("input[name=deposit_checked]").is(":checked") ) {
    $("input[name=deposit_value]").attr("disabled", false);
} else {
    $("input[name=deposit_value]").attr("disabled", true);
}

})
```

to save time, I tried using .each() and .next() function but no luck:

```
$("#form input[type=checkbox]").each(function() { 
$(this).change(function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
  $(this).next().attr("disabled", false);
   } else {
  $(this).next().attr("disabled", true);
   }
})
})
```

Comment: Your code works, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize DOM objects selection, cover inputs in somethings like span.

You can see this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4mQR/

```
<form id="form">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deposit_checked"> 
    <input type="text" name="deposit_value">
  </span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="booking_checked"> 
    <input type="text" name="booking_value">
  </span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="referral_checked"> 
    <input type="text" name="referral_value">
  </span>
</form>
```

JS code

```
$('#form input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  var obj = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]');
  obj.attr('disabled', !obj.attr('disabled'));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You were setting wrong value for the `disabled` attribute. Here is the fix:

```
$("#form input[type=checkbox]").each(function() { 
$(this).change(function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
  $(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
   } else {
  $(this).next().attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
})
})
```

Here is the working example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ySd/). Note that the all the javascript should be declared in the `$(window).load()` handler.

Comment: Please see the updated post with reference to the working example at jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$('#form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
   var t = $(this);
    t.next().attr('disabled', ! t.is(':checked'));
});
```

Remember to set the fields' and checkboxes' state in the beginning. For example: all unchecked and disabled.

+You may want to change the #form bit in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want to hide n show the texbox respective to its checkbox, so you can do this by attaching change event, this is how it is done:
`change` event handler is fired every time the value of the check box is changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.chkboxClass').bind('change', function () {

   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     $(this).next('.txtboxclass').hide();
   else
     $(this).next('.txtboxclass').show();

  });
});
```

where `.chkboxclass` is class for all checkboxes and `.txtboxclass` is class for all textboxes